# PayPal payment_status always Pending when I use Sandbox

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I am using the `PayPal IPN` feature but I keep getting `_POST[payment_status] = Pending` when I make a test using the Sandbox. Because of that, I can't test the full purchase to make sure the whole process works properly.

Here is my code:

```
// Set the request paramaeter
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

// Run through the posted array
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    // If magic quotes is enabled strip slashes
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        $_POST[$key] = stripslashes($value);
        $value = stripslashes($value);
    }
    $value = urlencode($value);
    // Add the value to the request parameter
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

$ch = curl_init();    // Starts the curl handler
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$paypal[$testing]); // Sets the paypal address for curl
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); // Returns result to a variable instead of echoing
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3); // Sets a time limit for curl in seconds (do not set too low)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); // Set curl to send data using post
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req); // Add the request parameters to the post
$result = curl_exec($ch); // run the curl process (and return the result to $result
curl_close($ch);

if (strcmp ($result, "VERIFIED") == 0) // It may seem strange but this function returns 0 if the result matches the string So you MUST check it is 0 and not just do strcmp ($result, "VERIFIED") (the if will fail as it will equate the result as false)
{
// It worked
// do my stuff
}else{

    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
        $post_str .="_POST[$key] = $value<br>";
    }

    $sub = "Paypal error";
    $mes = "$post_str";
    mailer($sub, $mes, $from, $to);

}
```

This is the error message I get in my email:

```
_POST[mc_gross] = 120.00
_POST[protection_eligibility] = Ineligible
_POST[address_status] = confirmed
_POST[payer_id] = QDZDYY4JWGFVG
_POST[tax] = 0.00
_POST[address_street] = 1 Maire-Victorin
_POST[payment_date] = 12:25:03 Apr 11, 2013 PDT
_POST[payment_status] = Pending
_POST[charset] = windows-1252
_POST[address_zip] = M5A 1E1
_POST[first_name] = gppl
_POST[address_country_code] = CA
_POST[address_name] = gppl Simard's Test Store
_POST[notify_version] = 3.7
_POST[custom] = 
_POST[payer_status] = verified
_POST[address_country] = Canada
_POST[address_city] = Toronto
_POST[quantity] = 1
_POST[verify_sign] = An5ns1Kso7MWUdW4ErQKJJJ4qi4-AjAXF3KMNcb6G83Jslw18dw.Ti32
_POST[payer_email] = 78h23d8712h3d@x.com
_POST[txn_id] = 2KU491796R824634N
_POST[payment_type] = instant
_POST[payer_business_name] = gppl x's Test Store
_POST[last_name] = Simard
_POST[address_state] = Ontario
_POST[receiver_email] = x@x.x
_POST[pending_reason] = unilateral
_POST[txn_type] = web_accept
_POST[item_name] = 926537
_POST[mc_currency] = CAD
_POST[item_number] = 
_POST[residence_country] = CA
_POST[test_ipn] = 1
_POST[handling_amount] = 0.00
_POST[transaction_subject] = 926537
_POST[payment_gross] = 
_POST[shipping] = 0.00
_POST[ipn_track_id] = c7dcef0b1c333
```

This error is really driving me nuts.
Just so you guys know, I already have the Payment review set to `off`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are useing sandbox, open developer.paypal.com->Dashboard->Accounts->facilitator@yourhost.com->Profile->Settings. Set 'Payment review' to 'Off'

Comment: Thanks. You just saved me a whole lot of hassles

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your accounts have a confirmed email address.  This typically happens when you send a payment to an account that doesn't have a confirmed email address.  So check the seller account, and make sure the email address is confirmed that you sent the payment to.

Comment: Hey guys, am stuck for the past 2 days on this. tried every bit of advice here & every where else I could find....The only thing I have tried cause I can't seem to find is 'Payment review'...this what I have on the developer.paypal sandbox page:[developer.paypal.sandbox-account](http://ndroidians.com/pics/developer_PP_SandBox.png)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem - I was sending PayPal my "live" payer_email, when I changed it to the business email in the sandbox it worked. same as my live email with ****-facilitator@yoursite.com

Answer (score 0):

Login to your Sandbox account with the business, and see if you have any 'Unclaimed' payments.  This could be because they are in a different currency than the one of your main account.